# grep file for string and copy directory to another directory

Tags: grep, cp

I have large number of directories with just one file --  index.html -- in each directory. I would want to use grep to look for pattern in  file and then copy the directory along with the file to another directory.

Example for copying files, I have seen, but I would want to copy the directory with the file in to another directory.

so say following are the list of matching files with directory using

```
grep -rl "string" source_dir


d1/index.htmk
d2/index.html
d3/index.html
```

...
...
a long list.

Now would want to copy to dest-dir so dest_dir looks like

```
.
..
d1/index.html
d2/index.html
d3/index.html
...
...
```

TIA

Comment: I assume you have a typo with the first code block, where `.htmk` should really be `.html`

Answer (score 2):

To preserve the directory structure, use [`cpio`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) in pass-through mode.  `cpio` is about as old as [`tar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) and used to have more advantages, but it has kind of slipped into [obscurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966409/cpio-vs-tar-and-cp/38236587#38236587).  I'm new to it and mostly followed an ancient [Linux Journal cpio guide](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1213) to build this command:

```
mkdir dest_dir
cd source_dir
grep -Zlr "string" . |cpio -p0dmv ../dest_dir
```

This passes a [null-terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)***** list of files matching your criteria through a pipeline directly into `cpio`, which is designed to take a list of files in this manner and then either archive or copy ("pass-through," `-p`).  We do the latter here, preserving the directory structure (`-d`) as well as modification times (`-m`).  I've set this to verbose (`-v`) so you can watch the progress.  If you're connecting via `ssh`, you might not want that since rendering each filename over the network can slow down the process.

***** Regarding null termination:  I used `grep -Zl` with `cpio -0` to work around the issue of file names containing newlines (don't do that[**!**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMQkF.jpg)); `grep -Zl` lists all matching files delimited by null characters (the only invalid character for a path) and `cpio -0` expects null-terminated inputs (as does `xargs -0`).

I originally recommended `tar` to create a temporary archive and `tar` again to extract it into the new location.  This used `xargs` to convert the file list into arguments since `tar` doesn't have the ability to accept its list of files within another file (or standard input, as `cpio` does), but `xargs` splits commands that are too long into multiple calls and `tar` can't extract the concatenated output******.

```
mkdir dest_dir
cd source_dir
grep -Zlr "string" . |xargs -0 tar -pc |tar -pxi --directory=../dest_dir
```

This makes your destination directory, enters the source directory, and runs grep with `-Zl` (null-terminated file list*****) and `-r` (recursive).  `xargs -0` turns that list into arguments for `tar`, which archives them.  Another `tar` instance then extracts them into the destination directory.

****** `xargs` defaults to `--max-procs=1` and should run one process at a time, resulting in multiple tarballs that are concatenated together.  The tar format is supposed to be able to handle this, though [further reading](https://superuser.com/questions/443611/bash-concatenating-tar-balls) suggested a simple solution is to add a `-i` ([ignore zeros](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_34.html#SEC75)) to the extracting `tar` to solve that problem.  I added it to the above code but have not tested it.

Comment: I expect around 1,80,000 directories max with single html file in each for a given string. So I hope this doesn't give problem.

Comment: 1,80,000. Total directories with single file is 0.6 million and that would sort into 30 odd sub based on the 30 "string" that will be run one at a time.

Comment: I tried and got this error:
xargs: tar: terminated by signal 13

Comment: Nuts.  I was hoping that `xargs` calling multiple `tar`s would work.  Okay, I've updated my answer to use `cpio`, which was built for this sort of thing.

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks.